# cannot read arabic text from url in java

Tags: java, http, arabic

I've a web service that prints the following text.

```
    [{"packid":"p101","title":"صفته 1","description":"شسیب: 1\r\nثق س: 50","linkfuntext":"funtext","linkshortstory":"short","linkfunpic":"pic","linkringtone":"ring","linkfungif":"gif","linkwallpaper":"wall","price":"500","buyid":"pack.fun.1","buyed":""},{"packid":"p102","title":"بسته صدا","description":" متن ها: 50\r\nصداها: 120\r\nتصاویر: 100\r\nتصاویر متحرک: 50\r\nداستان کوتاه: 20","linkfuntext":"","linkshortstory":"","linkfunpic":"","linkringtone":"","linkfungif":"","linkwallpaper":"","price":"1200","buyid":"fun.pack.2","buyed":""}]
```

When I try to read it in java I receive it in the following format

```
[{"packid":"p101","title":"&#1589;&#1601;&#1578;&#1607; 1","description":"&#1588;&#1587;&#1740;&#1576;: 1\r\n&#1579;&#1602; &#1587;: 50","linkfuntext":"funtext","linkshortstory":"short","linkfunpic":"pic","linkringtone":"ring","linkfungif":"gif","linkwallpaper":"wall","price":"500","buyid":"pack.fun.1","buyed":""},{"packid":"p102","title":"&#1576;&#1587;&#1578;&#1607; &#1589;&#1583;&#1575;","description":" &#1605;&#1578;&#1606; &#1607;&#1575;: 50\r\n&#1589;&#1583;&#1575;&#1607;&#1575;: 120\r\n&#1578;&#1589;&#1575;&#1608;&#1740;&#1585;: 100\r\n&#1578;&#1589;&#1575;&#1608;&#1740;&#1585; &#1605;&#1578;&#1581;&#1585;&#1705;: 50\r\n&#1583;&#1575;&#1587;&#1578;&#1575;&#1606; &#1705;&#1608;&#1578;&#1575;&#1607;: 20","linkfuntext":"","linkshortstory":"","linkfunpic":"","linkringtone":"","linkfungif":"","linkwallpaper":"","price":"1200","buyid":"fun.pack.2","buyed":""}]
```

I've tried changing the character set to UTF-8 as well as ISO-8859-6 but still no luck. When I print the text on console it is printed correctly which means  there is no issue in character set of eclipse or console. Also I've tried changing the character set of string that is storing the text, but same issue.

```
String serverOutput = new String(TEXT_FROM_SERVER.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
```

Here is my code that gets output from web service

```
 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();    
 InputStream is = entity.getContent();
 String serverOutput = convertStreamToString(is);

 private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        Reader rd = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try { 

            rd = new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8");

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        reader = new BufferedReader(rd);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append((line + "\n"));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I wonder when hieroglyphs, gang signs and scents will be allowed in URL.

Comment: that's actually Json array from php.

Answer (score 0):

you need to unescape those HTML characters, and you can do so with a method from Apache Commons Lang called `unescapeHtml`. More info [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html).

Example:

```
String afterDecoding = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(beforeDecoding);
```

Comment: String that is storing web service output ? serverOutput in my code ?